# Audio disposing problems using AudioVideoPlayback library

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, audiovideoplayback

I'm trying to make playlist, where music plays one after another. I need to `Dispose()` `Audio`, when it finishes, because memory leak will occur. I wrote this code:

```
Audio a = new Audio(@"Music\Title.ogg");
a.Ending += new EventHandler((sender, e) => { (sender as Audio).Dispose(); });
a.Play();
```

The problem is that I have `System.AccessViolationException` in `Application.Run(new MainForm());`: `Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt`. It happens in ending event handler right after music finishes playing.
So, how can I play some music files one after another and dispose previous audio afer it finishes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't dispose `Audio` inside it's own event because this class may want to do some bookkeeping work after invoking your handler.

I don't know logic of your applications but here are some idea, try to call `Open` on this object inside event handler. It should be smart enough to dispose old data and load new.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to make `new Audio` and it didn't dispose resources. `Open` does what I want.